# iphone how to manage memory when frequently loading images

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I'm currently coding my app that loads images frequently (but not the same images). As far as I test it out, there's no memory leak problem, but the memory usage of the app increases as I load up different images. It means the app will eventually gets killed by OS when it hits memory cap. I inspected through instrument and I found that a lot of memory was being held by NSConcreteData.

[image: memory allocation after the view is dismissed]

```
//from different thread, and pass data to main thread
NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
//at main, data to uiimage
imgView.image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
```

When the view is dismissed and all allocated memories get return to heap, it seems like the memory
I allocate for NSData keep presents in the memory and therefore the memory usage of the app increases compared to what it was before it loaded images. I'm not sure if this is normal behavior.
Or is it bad practice to pass allocated memory between different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not help in your exact case, but this is often reduced by paying closer attention to your autorelease stack growth. You should be able to reduce the problem by wrapping those heavy creators (data from url, image with data) in autorelease pool blocks.

```
@autoreleasepool { work with large NSObjects here }
```

or, depending on the system you must deploy for:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
work with large NSObjects here
[pool release];
```

If you can use `@autoreleasepool`, do so. it's slightly better because it interfaces with the underlying autorelease stacks directly. If you need backwards compatibility, then use `NSAutoreleasePool`. At a higher level, they really serve the same purpose, in the sense that you should be able to interchange their implementations in your program without introducing new issues. Therefore, it really comes down to the minimum OS you are targeting and the build settings you have specified for your project when deciding which to use.

You should wrap your handling and creation of large (or many) allocations in autorelease blocks because autoreleased objects are sent release messages "at some point in the future". By creating and destroying that autorelease pool explicitly (and by using autorelease less often), you allow many of these objects to be destroyed much sooner.

As to why this can be good in addition to simply not using autorelease in your program:  clients and system libraries may end up adding your big/numerous images/`NSData`s to the autorelease pools. Autorelease pools are like (thread local) stacks -- when you destroy your local pool, all those autorelease messages made while your pool was on top will be fulfilled, and the autoreleased objects will receive their release messages.

> Or is it bad practice to pass allocated memory between different threads?

Remember that you should message your UIKit and AppKit objects from the main thread. In Cocoa, many libraries may specify their threading models. NSData follows the Foundation threading model. The objects are not explicitly thread safe, but they are safe to use if you read and/or write from no more than one thread at any given time (that is, use a lock whenever you need to use it in a MT context, or pass copies). Passing and sharing data/objects is not a bad practice, it's necessary (or the logical solution) at times. There is a slight catch saying it's 'not bad': many people do not understand multithreading and shared resources well (it is not a trivial skill to learn for many).

Comment: whats difference between explicitly declaring NSAutoreleasePool and just use variable with autoreleasepool?

Comment: @REALFREE comments/response expanded and moved to updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Autorelease is less precise than explicitly releasing.

```
//on background thread data's retain count will now be 1
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];


//on main thread (I'm assuming .image is a retained property)
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
imgView.image = newImage;
[data release];
[newImage release];
```

Answer (score 0):

try open Allocation to calculate memory,
and when every time you want to release something,
Make it to be nil first, make sure no one is using this variable.
Otherwise, it crash.

Make Variable equal to nil, before release.